# is there a way to defined two path in JBehave story

Tags: java, jbehave

I'm have a story where I need to supply the JSON config file path and a tool path and pass these two paths to the python script?

when I try to add a second path next to tool path it uses all the string after the path as path :/
is there a way how to supply two paths in 'Given'?

story looks like

```
Scenario: Verify Certificate and Cipher misconfiguration

Given TestSSL tool  path 'C:\Users\Desktop\SSLTLS\testssl.sh-3.0' 
Then Certificate and Cipher check should return 0 for successful security-check
```

java code

```
@Given("TestSSL tool  path '$path'")
public void get_TestSSL_path(@Named("path") String path)
{
    try
    {
        Paths.get(path);
        toolPath = path;
    }
    catch (InvalidPathException | NullPointerException ex)
    {
    }
}

@Then("Certificate and Cipher check  should return 0 for successful security-check")
public void verify_cipher_and_certificate_attributes() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    String pythonFileName = "./scripts/python/security_misconfiguration_SSL_TLS.py";
    String fullcmdCommand = jsonpath + " " + toolPath ;
    System.out.println("Full path : " +fullcmdCommand);
    int script_result = Utilities.runPythonScript(pythonFileName, fullcmdCommand);
    Assert.assertEquals(0, script_result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should change the step input parameter to Collection, for example:

```java
@Given("TestSSL tool paths '$paths'")
public void get_TestSSL_path(@Named("paths") List<String> paths)
...
```

2. Separate input data using comma, for example:

```gherkin
Given TestSSL tool paths 'C:\Users\Desktop\SSLTLS\testssl.sh-3.0, C:\Users\Desktop\SSLTLS\testssl.sh-4.0'
```